# Is user credentials needed if mutual TLS authentication is setup between IBM MQ and Java client?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am looking at one scenario where I do not need to send the username/password explicitly when mutual TLS authentication is already setup between IBM MQ and my Java Client using self signed certificates.
I tried this in code, and what I noticed is when I don't send the credentials, then MQ receives the user id which the client application is running under and check the authorization access for same ID, ex. my windows user id, linux users where this code is running from , and if I send the credentials, then the passed userID is checked for authorization access at MQ end.

Here is the code snippet for creating context

```
        context = connectionfactory.createContext(userID,password); this send the userID
       //context = connectionfactory.createContext();   //This sends the logged on user info
        destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);
        TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is 2");
        producer = context.createProducer();
        producer.send(destination, message);
```

Could someone please help me to understand this behavior. Is this expected?

Comment: If you want the client cert to be your "authentication" then you would want to set up the SVRCONN channel either directly or with CHLAUTH rules to allow only expected certs to connect **AND** specify a specific MCAUSER.

Comment: @JoshMc you mean, the authentication can be handled using Client Cert and authorization can be used using MCAUSER?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @JoshMc is this the standard use-case? Do people use this kind of approach in real production scenarios?

Comment: Yes it is.   Before v8.0 it was the only way to provide and authentication with native IBM MQ functionality.   You could do username/password authentication using security exits, but you would need to write your own or purchase those.

Comment: @JoshMc, just one more thing, why the Logged in userId is getting passed when nothing is provided? I guess it is not preferred to rely on it for authorization.

Comment: This is the default value that is passed from the client.   If the queue manager is allowing that then it is not secure.  You could easily provide any username you want by simply passing a empty password.  A username should not be trusted from the client unless you are doing CONNAITH and validating the password.

Comment: @JoshMc, then providing MCAUSER at the MQ side, is the right approach for this scenario. So, that even the user info is null in request, the authorization will happen again MCAUSER and let the authentication happen through Mutual TLS.

Comment: First off don't use self-signed certificates.  Secondly, what you are trying to setup means that anyone who grabs the certificate can access the channel and pretend to be a different user (the channel's MCAUSER attribute overrides any and all incoming UserIds).  Use CA certificate for channel encryption and send the UserId and Password for authentication that is the preferred way and leave the MCAUSER attribute blank.

Comment: @Roger then what is the purpose of MCAUSER ?

Comment: It goes back to the beginning of IBM MQ (aka MQSeries) when a customer wanted to hard-code a UserId for all connections on a particular channel.  It was a bad idea back then and is still a bad idea.  i.e. before companies worried about security.

Comment: @Roger any insight why this would be a bad idea. Is there restriction on number of channel definitions? Or does having hundreds/thousands definitions impact performance?

If caller always uses same identity and identity is proven with a certificate, I don't see security benefits in providing username + password. Decade or two ago when no one was using mTLS, username + password made sense.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen what is a bad idea?  For certificates, are you asking about mutual authentication?  If you are referring to the QMgr certificate then how does anyone distinguish between application and another?  You should open your own question and given details what you are looking for.

Comment: @Roger Both my and original question was about mutual TLS authentication. One can use CHLAUTH rules for mapping specific certificate to a user (MCAUSER) with SSLPEERMAP. I'm just wondering why anyone would use both username + password  and mTLS authentication (SSLPEERMAP).

Comment: @SamiKorhonen you don't answer my questions, so it is difficult to help you.  Are you trying to setup mutual authentication?  i.e. every client has it OWN certificate (not queue manager certificate).  If yes, then you don't need UserId/Password authentication, although it is still useful.  But if you are NOT doing mutual authentication then that means all MQ clients are ONLY using the queue manager certificate.  Hence, how do you know the difference between application "A" and application "B".

Comment: @Roger Yes, and the original author wrote about mutual authentication as well (mTLS) Mutual TLS authentication always includes client specific certificates. That's why your comment left me wondering

Comment: @JoshMc can you specify how to set CHLAUTH Rules to allow only expected certs? so that we don't send userId and password for authentication.

Comment: @VanshajBehl you need to enable the CHLAUTH records and then create the records for the channel which you will be accessing. When you create the record, you specify the Distinguished Names (DNs) and map it to MCAUSER which will perform the tasks for you. MCAUSER in use should  be authorized for Objects you are interested in. DNs is what you are looking for. You can specify the CN, ORG etc to identify the cert and map it to a specific user.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=reference-set-chlauth-create-modify-channel-authentication-record